# Вывод города в Битрикс (Для статистической странцы)

Tags: битрикс

Делаю вывод города в Битрикс с помощью модуля https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/dev2fun.multidomain/#tab-install-link

На странице города вывожу в H1. Все работает.

```
<?=Dev2fun\MultiDomain\Base::GetCurrentDomain()['UF_NAME'] ?? 'Москве' ?>
```

Не могу понять как сделать вывод города в meta title

```
// $APPLICATION->SetTitle("title", "Купить кухню в "тут должно выводиться название города в зависимости от региона");
```

Пробовал так

```
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("<?=Dev2fun\\MultiDomain\\Base::GetCurrentDomain()['UF_NAME'] ?? 'Москве' ?>");
```

Но в title вообще пропадает весь текст.

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести название города в meta title

Сделать вывод города в SEO настройках инфоблока не могу, так как страница не динамическая, а статистическая.

Название города выводится **UF_NAME**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задать так:

```
$myTitle = "Купить кухню в " . (Dev2fun\MultiDomain\Base::GetCurrentDomain()['UF_NAME'] ?? 'Москве');
$APPLICATION->SetTitle($myTitle);
```

то вывод заголовка на странице делается c помощью метода `$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()`.

Если же вам нужен meta title, то нужно использовать

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $myTitle);
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы название города было в середине title. Сейчас город в конце.

Например сделать Купить кухню в "Название города" недорого. Подскажите пожалуйста как код изменить для этого?

Comment: ```$city = (Dev2fun\MultiDomain\Base::GetCurrentDomain()['UF_NAME'] ?? 'Москве'); $myTitle = "Купить кухню в $city недорого";```